# Symantec EV SSL with Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku

Does anyone know how to set up a Symantec EV SSL Certificate on Heroku?  I'm super confused at the moment.  They offer me download of an X.509 Cert and a PKCS7 Cert.  In addition, I can download Apache Bundle, Plesk Bundle, Certificate Issuer, or Intermediate CA 1.  I'm lost.